# Efficiency of Preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, loops, performance, preg-replace

### Executive Summary:

**`preg_replace()` ran faster than string comparisons. Why? Shouldn't regular expressions be slower?**

---

In a [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487781/php-check-string-for-certain-words/3487789#3487789) about detecting any of an array of disallowed substrings within a given input, I suggested comparing the result of a `preg_replace()` call to the original input, since `preg_replace()` can take an array of patterns as input. Thus my method for this could be a single `if` whereas the other solutions required one (or many) loops.

I'm not interested in debating my answer, because really it is less readable/maintainable than the loops. My answer there still holds a -1, and I'll accept that for readability/ease of maintenance, but the biggest fault pointed out with my method was a lack of efficiency. That got me curious, and led me to do some testing. My results were a bit surprising to me: with all other factors held equal, `preg_replace()` was *faster* than any of the other methods.

**Can you explain why this was the case?**

My code for these tests can be found below, along with the results:

```
$input = "In a recent question about detecting any of an array of disallowed substrings within a given input, I suggested comparing the result of a `preg_replace()` call to the original input, since `preg_replace()` can take an array of patterns as input. Thus my method for this could be a single `if` whereas the other solutions required one (or many) loops. I'm not interested in debating my answer, because really it is less readable/maintainable than the loops. However, the biggest fault pointed out with my method was a lack of efficiency. That got me curious, and led me to do some testing. My results were a bit surprising to me: with all other factors held equal, `preg_replace()` was **faster** than any of the other methods. Can you explain why this was the case?";
$input2 = "Short sentence - no matches";
$input3 = "Word";
$input4 = "Short sentence - matches loop";

$start1 = microtime(true);
$rejectedStrs = array("loop", "efficiency", "explain");
$p_matches = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++) {
    if (str_check($rejectedStrs, $input)) $p_matches++;
    if (str_check($rejectedStrs, $input2)) $p_matches++;
    if (str_check($rejectedStrs, $input3)) $p_matches++;
    if (str_check($rejectedStrs, $input4)) $p_matches++;
}

$start2 = microtime(true);
$rejectedStrs = array("loop", "efficiency", "explain");
$l_matches = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++) {
    if (loop_check($rejectedStrs, $input)) $l_matches++;
    if (loop_check($rejectedStrs, $input2)) $l_matches++;
    if (loop_check($rejectedStrs, $input3)) $l_matches++;
    if (loop_check($rejectedStrs, $input4)) $l_matches++;
}

$start3 = microtime(true);
$rejectedStrs = array("/loop/", "/efficiency/", "/explain/");
$s_matches = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++) {
    if (preg_check($rejectedStrs, $input)) $s_matches++;
    if (preg_check($rejectedStrs, $input2)) $s_matches++;
    if (preg_check($rejectedStrs, $input3)) $s_matches++;
    if (preg_check($rejectedStrs, $input4)) $s_matches++;
}

$end = microtime(true);
echo $p_matches." ".$l_matches." ".$s_matches."\n";
echo "str_match: ".$start1." ".$start2."= ".($start2-$start1)."\nloop_match: ".$start2." ".$start3."=".($start3-$start2)."\npreg_match: ".$start3." ".$end."=".($end-$start3);

function preg_check($rejectedStrs, $input) {
    if($input == preg_replace($rejectedStrs, "", $input)) 
        return true;
    return false;
}

function loop_check($badwords, $string) {

    foreach (str_word_count($string, 1) as $word) {
        foreach ($badwords as $bw) {
            if (stripos($word, $bw) === 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

function str_check($badwords, $str) {
    foreach ($badwords as $word) {
        if (stripos(" $str ", " $word ") !== false) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

### Results

> 20000 20000 20000
>
> str_match: 1282270516.6934 1282270518.5881= 1.894730091095
>
> loop_match: 1282270518.5881 1282270523.0943=4.5061857700348
>
> preg_match: 1282270523.0943 1282270523.6191=0.52475500106812

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's first look at `preg_check` and `loop_check`. Both of them will have to traverse the entire string, and they will have to check each of the individual words in each traversal. So their behavior will at least be `O(n*m)`, where `n` is the length of the string and `m` the number of bad words. You can test this by running the algorithm with increasing values of `n` and `m` and plotting the 3D graphs (however, you may, or may not, have to run it with very high values of `n` and `m` to see this behavior).

`loop_check` is **more** (asymptoticly) efficient here. The reason is that the number of words a string has is not proportional to their length -- I seem to recall it typically follows a logarithmic function. It probably uses a hash table to store the words it finds through the way, which is done in average constant time (if we ignore that we may have to rebuild the hash table from time to time to accommodate more elements).

Therefore `loop_check` will have an asymptotic behavior that follows something like `n + m * log(n)`, which is better than `n*m`.

Now, this refers to the asymptotic behavior of the algorithms, i.e., when `m` and `n` grow very (and it may require "very very") large. For small values of `m` and `n` the constants play a big part. In particular, execution of PHP opcodes and PHP function calls are more costly than the same task  implemented in C, just one function call away. This doesn't make the regex algorithm faster, it just makes it faster for small values of `m` and `n`.

Comment: Interesting. I had assumed that the nested nature of `loop_check` would lead its performance to *worsen* as the size of inputs increased. I went ahead and tested this with the same code as in the question, but inputs of ~20x `$input` along with ~50 bad words. And to your point, I got the results you expected: `loop_check` far outperformed, at apx 14s vs 21s and 25s for `preg_check` and `str_check`. In the end, I guess it comes down to how long a string you expect to check on average, and how many words you will check against.

Comment: @JGB you can't just look at the loops you see in the PHP code; the internal functions' implementations are also capable to loop, do recursive calls, etc. Also important is how many times they loop.

Comment: @JGB And I repeat, if you care about spee, you can write an algoritm that turns the bad words into a trie tree and is able to run in O(n). If you implement in C in a PHP extension, you can be sure it'll also beat the other solutions from small values of m and n.

Comment: @JGB Sorry, a trie implementation will be O(n+m), because building the trie takes linear time on `m`. But it's still better than O(n + m * log(n)).

Answer (score 2):

> Can you explain why this was the case?

Easy.  preg_match is implemented in C.  The other solutions are implemented in PHP.  Now, that doesn't mean a regex will *always* be faster than the equivalent PHP, but most of the time, it probably will be.

I recently had a similar situation, where I had a function (a CamelCase converter) that was being called 10s of thousands of times, and taking a fair amount of CPU (I profiled).  I tried every PHP reimplementation I could dream up.  The `preg_replace` was always faster.  In the end, I left the function as it was, and memoized it, which did the trick.

In many cases, the fewer PHP statements executed, the better.  If you can replace a loop with a single call to a function that's implemented in C under the hood, that may be your best bet.

> really it is less readable/maintainable than the loops

I disagree.  One-liners are as simple as it gets.  Although I'd probably go with something more like

```
function preg_check($rejectedStrs, $input) {
    return preg_match($rejectedStrs, "", $input);
}
```

Comment: Note that preg_match wasn't viable for this, since it only accepts a single pattern. Still, your point holds. I hadn't considered that built-ins would be implemented in a compiled language. Would it change things if I were using something like APC to speed up my php?

Comment: As to the loops vs one-liners, I said loops were more readable/maintainable because the intention is more clear and understandable to the average programmer. As evidenced by the -1 my answer still holds on the question I'm referencing.

Comment: I was very tempted to downvote this. "preg_match is implemented in C" is a simplistic explanation. A more time complex algorithm in C will always be (asymptotically) slower than one in PHP.

Comment: @Artefacto: Would you agree that this is the reason for the performance I saw in my original tests?

Comment: "Note that preg_match wasn't viable for this, since it only accepts a single pattern" -- you can always combine multiple words into a single pattern: `preg_match('/(loop|efficiency|explain)/', $str);`